# PyQt6: Get QGraphicsItem in a group which is at a specific position

Tags: pyqt, qgraphicsscene

The QGraphicsScene class has a method .itemAt which returns the top-most item on the scene at specified coordinates (x, y). However, what if you don't want to get the top-most item? I would like to delete an item at coordinates (x, y) which is contained in a specific QGraphicsItemGroup when the mouse is dragged while the left mouse button is held. The QGraphicsItemGroup has a method .contains which can detect if any item in the group is at (x, y), but doesn't actually return an object at this point.

I tried using the .setZValue method to temporarily move the item group to the top level using the following function which executes when the mouse is moved while the left mouse button is held:

```
if itemGroup contains(QPointF(x, y)):
    itemGroup.setZValue(100)
    oldItem = scene.itemAt(x, y, QTransform())
    itemGroup.removeItem(oldItem)
    scene.removeItem(oldItem)
    itemGroup.setZValue(oldZvalue)
```

Here itemGroup is the QGraphicsItemGroup, scene is the QGraphicsScene, and oldZvalue is the Z-value of the item group prior to changing it for the purposes of deletion. This unfortunately deletes things outside the item group.

Of course, I could just iterate through all items in the group and check their positions, but I would hope there is a better way.

Comment: I don't understand: is the "target" item behind another? Can you try to clarify the context of the items, including their stacking order? Besides, `contains()` is common to all QGraphicsItems, not just QGraphicsItemGroup, and QGraphicsScene has other related functions that don't just return the topmost item, but *all* existing items at a certain coordinate: see all overloads of `items()` in the QGraphicsScene documentation.

Comment: @musicamante I have a grid drawn on a black background, where the gridlines are of type QGraphicsLineItem. Inside the grid cells, I want to place blocks of "terrain", and I want to be able to delete the terrain blocks without deleting the grid lines. The grid lines are usually above the terrain in Z-value. At any rate, iterating over QGraphicsScene.items(QPoint(x, y)) and checking for items in the terrain group seems satisfactory. Thank you!

Comment: If the grid is for the whole scene, you should consider overriding [`drawForeground()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#drawForeground) instead of using line items (there's a similar function for QGraphicsView too), which has the benefit of allowing virtually "infinite" grid lines, no matter the scene size, without the need to create individual lines. If the grid should be enclosed within an item that contains the children you need to manage (and delete), you can do the same by overriding the `paint()` of that item, ensuring that its children have the `ItemStacksBehindParent` flag set.